# dynamic selected option using variables from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

After finally getting this to work, I thought I'd post it in case it maybe
I was having trouble working to populate a few sets of dropdown select tags.
I had researched a number of similar submissions and solutions, but I still couldn't find the answers I'd been looking for.

@Ronser had helped me to test through my queries, which lead me to learning more about how the arrays actually worked. I realised I needed to go back and to update the **access** column in **TABLE 1** to **access_id**. (I should've indexed these originally).

**Table 1:** app_generalData
app_id,
title,
status_id,
category_id,
tags,
access_id

**Table 2:** app_access
 
access_id,
access_title

**Desired result(s):**
**Objective 1:** Show/echo the selected option (stored in **app_access** table)

**Objective 2:**
Build these queries with variables to allow for easy updating for adding new dropdowns.

**Resulting HTML:**

```
<select name="access"><option "">Global</option>\n<option " selected ">Corporate</option>\n<option "">Local Site</option>\n</select>
```

**Code:**

```
<?php

//connect to the database
require_once('connectvars.php');

// global variable for this populating this dropdown
$dropdown =         "access";
$before_var =       "app_";
$column1=           $before_var.$dropdown;
$after_var =        "_title";
$column2=           $dropdown.$after_var;
$id_var=            "_id";
$dropdown_table_id= $dropdown.$id_var;

$optionsList = array();

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

echo '<select name="' . $dropdown . '">';

// See if we're viewing a selected app or are we creating a new app
if (isset($_GET['app_id'])) {
          // print_r($_GET); // GET is Successful

  // 'if' [app_id] is appended in the url

      // STEP 1: Get the stored value of the SELECTED from mysql

          // Get "selected item" (id) from app_generalData (table) with the "selected app" (id)
          $option = "SELECT  ".$dropdown_table_id." FROM app_generalData WHERE app_id ='" . $_GET['app_id'] . "'";

          // submit the select statement
          // Get & store the value of "selected" <option>
          $selected_option = mysqli_query($dbc, $option) 
              or die(mysql_error());
          $row_1=mysqli_fetch_array($selected_option);

      // STEP 2: Build the SELECT input

          // Set the array of data to populate dropdown list <option>s
          $options = "SELECT * FROM ".$column1." ORDER BY ".$dropdown_table_id."";
                // NOTE: print_r($options)...SELECT access_title FROM app_access ORDER BY access_id
            $selected_options = mysqli_query($dbc, $options)
                or die(mysqli_error());

            $kk     = 0;   //initialize kk
           while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($selected_options)) {

                $selected ='';
                if($row_1["$dropdown_table_id"]==$row_2["$dropdown_table_id"]) {
                $selected=' selected ';
                }
                $optionsList[$kk++] ='<option "' . $selected . '">' . $row_2["$column2"] . '</option>';
           }

          // Echo the <option>s
              $optionCount = count($optionsList);
              for($i=0;$i<$optionCount;$i++) {
                  echo $optionsList[$i].'\n';
              }

    }
    else {
        // Action 'if' no [app_id] is appended in the url
    };
    // close the last <select> tag
    echo '</select>';

    // close the last database
    mysqli_close($dbc); 

?>
```

Comment: check with `print_r($_GET);` to verify the data flow.. any errors???

Comment: @Ronser I placed the `print_r($_GET);` directly after `if (isset($_GET['app_id'])) {`. It produced `Array ( [app_id] => 1 )`. Looks right to me.

Comment: `print_r($_GET);`,`print_r($_POST);`,`print_r($_SESSION);` is generally used at the top to know what are the elements passed/initialized.

Comment: see the change posted and check the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//connect to the database
require_once('connectvars.php');

// global variable for this populating this dropdown
$dropdown =         "access";
$before_var =       "app_";
$column1=           $before_var.$dropdown;
$after_var =        "_title";
$column2=           $dropdown.$after_var;
$id_var=            "_id";
$dropdown_table_id= $dropdown.$id_var;

$optionsList = array();

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

echo '<select name="' . $dropdown . '">';

// See if we're viewing a selected app or are we creating a new app
if (isset($_GET['app_id'])) {
          // print_r($_GET); // GET is Successful

  // 'if' [app_id] is appended in the url

      // STEP 1: Get the stored value of the SELECTED from mysql

          // Get "selected item" (id) from app_generalData (table) with the "selected app" (id)
          $option = "SELECT  ".$dropdown_table_id." FROM app_generalData WHERE app_id ='" . $_GET['app_id'] . "'";

          // submit the select statement
          // Get & store the value of "selected" <option>
          $selected_option = mysqli_query($dbc, $option) 
              or die(mysql_error());
          $row_1=mysqli_fetch_array($selected_option);

      // STEP 2: Build the SELECT "selected" and <options>

          // Set the array of data to populate dropdown list <option>s
          $options = "SELECT * FROM ".$column1." ORDER BY ".$dropdown_table_id."";
                // NOTE: print_r($options)...SELECT access_title FROM app_access ORDER BY access_id
            $selected_options = mysqli_query($dbc, $options)
                or die(mysqli_error());

            $kk     = 0;   //initialize kk
           while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($selected_options)) {

                $selected ='';
                // Compare access_id from table1 against access_id from table2
                if($row_1["$dropdown_table_id"]==$row_2["$dropdown_table_id"]) {
                $selected=' selected ';
                }
                $optionsList[$kk++] ='<option "' . $selected . '">' . $row_2["$column2"] . '</option>';
           }

          // Echo the <option>s
              $optionCount = count($optionsList);
              for($i=0;$i<$optionCount;$i++) {
                  echo $optionsList[$i].'\n';
              }

    }
    else {
        // Action 'if' no [app_id] is appended in the url
    };
    // close the last <select> tag
    echo '</select>';

    // close the last database
    mysqli_close($dbc); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

1. Check for the 'app_id'.
2. Print the sql query and run directly in your mysql.

If it returns no rows or error please verify the sql query.

Comment: @Ronser and @Bincy-Kuriakose See above that  <br />
1. The app_id did print the correct data.
2. SQL Query tested directly in mysql
    - The 1st sql query produced `SELECT access FROM app_generalData WHERE app_id ='1'`
        * mysql produced `corporate`, which is the correct result from correct the access column
    - The 2nd sql query produced `SELECT access_title FROM app_access ORDER BY access_id
        * mysql query produced: the correct column of the desired table

Answer (score 1):

**try this...**

```
     $options = "SELECT ".$column2." FROM ".$column1." ORDER BY ".$dropdown_table_id."";
      $kk     = 0;   //initialize kk
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($options)) {
          $selected ='';
          if($selected_option==$row["$column2"]) {
          $selected=' selected ';
      }
      $optionsList[$kk++] ='<option "' . $selected . '">' . $row["$column2"] . '</option>';          
     //try this change. or

     echo '<option "' . $selected . '">' . $row["$column2"] . '</option>'; //print it here itself
     }

    print_r($optionsList);
```

Comment: I've patched in this snippet. The print_r resulted in `Array ( ) `

Comment: was it an empty array after trying the above code??

Comment: Yes. As you've helped me to realise I could test each step with print_r, I've gone back through &...I think I've found something: I ran a `print_r($selected_option);` and it produced `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )` That didn't seem right, so I readdressed the mysqli_fetch_array to `$row_1=mysqli_fetch_array(**$selected_option**);`
      print_r($row_1);` gave me `Array ( [0] => corporate [access] => corporate ) `. Getting close... I've changed the `if` statement in your `while` to `if($row_1==`. Still nothing..

Comment: hope you are nearing... first `print_r($row);` to know the values.. you can also use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);  echo "</pre>";` inorder to align a large array... then have you tried the above solution??

Comment: When i print_r($row); as such `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($options)) { print_r($row);...` Nothing comes up.

Comment: then there is something wrong with your query check that first

Comment: Could it have something to do with $options calling the specified column instead of *? @Ronser

Comment: Ok...just found a major oversight...After looking back at the 2nd query (for $options), I'd realised forgotten to add `$selected_options = mysqli_query($dbc, $options)`. Now, I'm getting the options from your $optionsList, but no "selected".

Comment: @Rosner After adding the db connect for the $options query, the print_r($row) produced the following:
Array ( [0] => Global [access_title] => Global )  
Array ( [0] => Corporate [access_title] => Corporate )
Array ( [0] => Local Site [access_title] => Local Site )

Comment: @Rosner To see what was actually being compared between $row_1==$row["$column2"]...`print_r($row['$column2']);` produced `GlobalCorporateLocal Site`. Shouldn't these be printing as separate values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63071/discussion-between-cpardon-and-ronser).